# ScrollView not scrolling to the end of inner LinearLayout's bottom margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I'm having issues with a Fragment consisting of a ScrollView containing a LinearLayout. I'm trying to create an effect where the LinearLayout has a white background and looks like a piece of paper scrolling on a coloured background. The way that I'm trying to achieve this is by having the ScrollView occupy the full space of the fragment and then the LinearLayout inside has `android:layout_margin="16dp"` to create the space around the "paper".

This way, the scroll bar of the ScrollView appears in the coloured background area, the margin at the top scrolls away along with the content and the margin at the bottom only scrolls in when one reaches the end.

Unfortunately in this configuration the ScrollView won't scroll all the way to the end and in fact cuts off a very small amount of the text at the bottom. I suspect that the ScrollView isn't taking into account its child's margins in its vertical scrolling distance. To solve this I've wrapped the LinearLayout in a FrameLayout which solves the issue, but seems superfluous. Any pointers on how to eliminate this unneeded container would be appreciated.

Note: setting `android:padding="16dp"` on the ScrollView and scrapping the margins doesn't have the desired effect, as then the padding appears on all four edges continuously, regardless of scroll position.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ArticleFragment" >

    <!-- This FrameLayout exists purely to force the outer ScrollView to respect
         the margins of the LinearLayout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@color/page_background" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textIsSelectable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textIsSelectable="true" />

       </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Tried setting `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to the `ScrollView`?

Comment: @AdilSoomro Yes, no joy. The size of the ScrollView isn't really an issue - it fills the space available to it appropriately. It's the area of scrolling that it provides - it doesn't allow scrolling to the very end of its contents when its immediate child has a margin. I believe the issue is caused by it not taking its child's margin into account when calculating the scrolling area.

Answer (score 6):

I remember having trouble with the `ScrollView` somehow not making it to the end of it's contents when the content layout had a top margin. I solved the problem with a little hack, adding an empty view to the end of the `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".ArticleFragment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:background="@color/page_background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:background="@color/page_background" />


        <!-- Add a little space to the end -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />

   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I used a similar empty view also in the beginning of the `LinearLayout` to avoid top/bottom margins completely.

EDIT: I just realised that you also wanted the end of the "paper" to show up when reaching the end of the view. In that case you might want to set the background color to the `TextView`s instead of the layout itself. Then make sure there's no margin between the title and the article (use padding as separation).

EDIT2: I should learn to check when the questions were asked... Well, maybe this still helps someone. :)

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but I've had issues with ScrollView being ill-behaved when wrapping FrameLayout. It also doesn't seem to consider the margins of contained layouts. You could replace the FrameLayout with another single-child LinearLayout, which should measure correctly. I would've removed the FrameLayout completely and simply added summed margin with padding on the inner layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="26dp"
            android:background="@color/page_background" >
<!--...-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd get rid of the `FrameLayout` and make the `LinearLayout` the child of the `ScrollView` with `match_parent` set as the layout height. If that still doesn't work, consider replacing the bottom margin with another arbitrary `View` with the desired height and background as the last item in the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Match_parent must be in scrollView. And child of scrollView must have heigh = "wrap_content".

Comment: Ah good point. The latter option would probably be best then.

Comment: Neither of these combinations solve the issue. Adding an extra view of the desired margin height at the end of the LinearLayout is slightly more gross than wrapping it in the FrameLayout, to be honest. Why is the ScrollView behaving in this way and ignoring the top and bottom margins?

Comment: @GrahamLyon Adding an extra view is actually less gross, because it doesn't impact view hierarchy. If you add a wrapping layout with paddings it will add one more layer to the view hierarchy, which impacts the rendering speed.